# How to remove selected index in a string using php?

Tags: php, for-loop

I am having a function like this,

```
<?php


function strReplace($text,$number) {

  for ($i=1; $i < strlen($text) ; $i++) {
    if (($i%$number) == 0) {
      $position = strpos($text,$text[$i]);
      $result = substr_replace($text,"",$position);
      echo $result;
    }
  }

}

strReplace("abcdefghij",3);

?>
```

I need to delete the 3,6,9 position of the string and i have used the above code but it gives the output as,

```
abcabcdefabcdefghi
```

And desired output is,

```
abcefhi
```

Comment: you can turn your entire string into an array like this : `$array = str_split($str);` and then use `array_splice($array, 3, 1);`  - Also `array_splice()` needs the offset, not the key!, as second parameter.

Comment: I need to use only string and it should not be converted into array..

Comment: _it should not be converted into array._ Why not? You can implode the array afterwards and get back your string

Answer (score 2):

Here is two ways to do this:

This loops over characters and add to a new string only if it is the first character or if the modulo is zero:

```
function strReplace($text,$number) {
    $str = '';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($text) ; $i++) {
        if ($i && ($i % $number) == 0) continue; // If $i > 0 or if $i is 3,6,9,...
        $str .= substr($text, $i, 1); // Add character to new string
    }
    return $str ;
}

echo strReplace("abcdefghij",3) ; // abcefhi
```

Or:

This will turn the input string into an array, and filter each entry to keep keys that match with the rule (first key or modulo is zero):

```
function strReplace($text,$number) {
    $str = str_split($text) ; // turn into ['a','b','c','d',...];
    $arr = array_filter($str, function($k) use ($number) {  // use $number into the function
         return !($k && $k % $number == 0) ; 
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY); // Use the keys (0,1,2..) as index of char in string
    return implode($arr) ; // convert the array to string
}

echo strReplace("abcdefghij",3) ; // abcefhi
```

Note that the functions above does not `echo` but returns the new string. The `echo` statement is only used in the call statement. This will allow you to re-use the function in other ways than just `echo`.